# How to get 2560x1440 resolution with dell u2715h hdmi 1.4

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, adapter

Hi I just bought a Dell U2715h (3x DP 1.2 in, 2x HDMI 1.4 in). 
I want to connect it to my Samsung laptop through HDMI (it only has HDMI and mini VGA outputs).

I want to use the native resolution and I saw that to get 2560x1440 I need to use display port.

Is there any adapter that I can use to get 2560x1440?

Answer (score 0):

Your monitor support two [HDMI 1.4 inputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4). These have a maximum resolution of 4096×2160p/30 Hz.

Thus you do not **need** to use DP, but if you use HDMI then the refresh rate will be rather low. This is fine for static images, but not when scrolling or gaming. And manhy people posted about loosing track of the mouse on 30Hz 4K TVs. I guess the same issue will happen with a monitor at 30Hz.

So I agree, we want to use the DisplayPort inputs. HDMI might work but is likely to be found lacking.

The three display ports on your monitor are DP 1.2, if you had a laptop which provided that it would just work, however as writting in your post you only have HDMI and VGA.

Now it gets harder. All we know is that you have 'a Samsung laptop'. Not a specific model. So we do not know which output is supported by the laptop.

If it has HDMI 1.2 or less then that port is useless for these resolutions and we will need to use the VGA output. I prefer not to though since VGA means we get to convert from digital information to analog and then back again to digital, loosing quality in the process.

So, lets assume your laptop has at least HDMI 1.3. Then it can provide the needed information for your screen on the HDMI output. Now we are looking for a HDMI >=1.3 to DP convertor. I googled for those and they can be found (not linking to those since the answers will vary over time, but you are looking for 'HDMI to Displayport adaptor` and for a model which supports more than 1920x1200. Those which I found are all rather expensive (€120+).

At this point it might be worth looking if you laptop has other options. E.g. f it supports external graphics cards via an expresscard slot, or if you mind running at a lower resolution until you get your next laptop.

Comment: Thanks Hennes first , I'm very appreciate your answer. its help me.
about my laptop , I do have  external graphics cards .
I have AMD Radeon HD 8750M.
and the Samsung model is 530U4E.
Can you show me which  HDMI to Displayport adaptor did you saw that supports more than 1920x1200 please ? 
And about the refresh rate , I will use only for photo editing and without gaming movies ect.